# Subscriptions in PayPal

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on integrating Recurring Payments functionality in Asp.Net based application where people can subscribe to a Service where they will be paying a monthly amount. I am trying to achieve the same using PayPal's [Subscription APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/). One another aspect is where people will be making payments using their Credit Card instead of PayPal's account. I have tried to search for a sample code where I can see that Credit Card information is passed to the Subscription API but unable to find the same. Can anyone points me to a sample code where this is implemented or guide me on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does provide a Subscription only API for PayPal payments or Guest Checkout where buyer's prompt to create PayPal personal account. To achieve a Credit card subscription I'd reckon to refer to Braintree Vaulting functionality wherein you can have both Credit Card & PayPal.

**Braintree Vault Overview:**
Our Braintree Vault securely stores customer information – including payment method information – so you can safely keep customers on file.

The Vault is used to process payments with our recurring billing feature, and can also be used for non-recurring transactions so your customers don't need to re-enter their information each time they make a purchase from you.

https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview

Thanks.